# Tooptip pointFormatters - HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Hi I am creating a pie chart using values from an API and I am creating a tooltip for each value. The values to be shown in the tooltip come from another API. How do I access another API values inside this tooltip?

Here is my code.

```
$scope.topUsersList = [
  {
    "ID": "1",
    "Display_Name": "Arun",
    "Module": "JRD",
    "Module_Hits": "25",
    "Total_Hits_by_User": "28"
  },
  {
    "ID": "1",
    "Display_Name": "Arun",
    "Module": "JRM",
    "Module_Hits": "3",
    "Total_Hits_by_User": "28"
  },
  {
    "ID": "2",
    "Display_Name": "Manohar",
    "Module": "JRD",
    "Module_Hits": "4",
    "Total_Hits_by_User": "9"
  },
  {
    "ID": "2",
    "Display_Name": "Manohar",
    "Module": "JRH",
    "Module_Hits": "3",
    "Total_Hits_by_User": "9"
  },
  {
    "ID": "2",
    "Display_Name": "Manohar",
    "Module": "JRM",
    "Module_Hits": "2",
    "Total_Hits_by_User": "9"
  },
  {
    "ID": "3",
    "Display_Name": "abcd",
    "Module": "JRM",
    "Module_Hits": "3",
    "Total_Hits_by_User": "3"
  },
  {
    "ID": "4",
    "Display_Name": "ghij",
    "Module": "JRM",
    "Module_Hits": "1",
    "Total_Hits_by_User": "1"
  }
];
```

This is the actual data to be mapped.

```
$scope.topUsers = [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "display_name": "Arun",
    "percentage_of_total": "68.29"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "display_name": "Manohar",
    "percentage_of_total": "21.95"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "display_name": "abcd",
    "percentage_of_total": "7.32"
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "display_name": "ghij",
    "percentage_of_total": "2.44"
  }
]
```

This is my code.

```
$scope.getTopUsers = function() {
    axios.get('/getTopUsersList')
        .then(function (res) {
            $scope.topUsersList = res.data.rows;
            console.log($scope.topUsersList);
        });
    axios.get('/getTopUsers')
        .then(function(res) {
            $scope.topUsers = res.data.rows;
            console.log($scope.topUsers);
            Highcharts.chart('container-topUsersStats', {
                chart: {
                    type: 'pie',
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Top 5 users Month-To-Date'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            format: '{point.name}: {point.y:.2f} %'
                        }
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px"><b>{point.name}</b></span><br>',
                    pointFormat: '<span>Module Hits</span>: <b>{$scope.topUsersList}</b><br/>'
                },
                series: [
                    {
                        name: 'Top Users',
                        colorByPoint: true,
                        data: $scope.topUsers.map(function(user) {
                            return {
                                name: user.display_name,
                                y: parseFloat(user.percentage_of_total)
                            };
                        })
                    }
                ]
            });
        });
};
```

So what I want to do is, when I hover over each pie, in the tooltip I should see the data from the topUsersList corresponding to that particular user.

Thanks and appreciate your help.

Comment: Could you please make a working example of your current code, this makes it a lot easier someone to experiment and try to make it work. Secondly, how should the tooltips look when there is 2 values in the lookup table with Id: 1? Adding an image would be helpful to understand your intentions

Comment: `tooltip.formatter` callback function allows you to refer to variables from scopes other than Highcharts': https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

Comment: @KamilKulig thanks man. Thats what I did. I did a map function and it renders a comma inside the html. Any idea how to remove that comma? Or should I post the code?

Comment: What comma? Please provide your code an screenshot.